# How to do slow motion effect in side view flash game with box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

As i am working on side view bike stunt game in which am trying to add slow motion effect when a bike performs stunts. 
Is there any solution for showing such kind of slow motion effect in Box2D. can anybody help me in this regard

Thanks and regards,

Chandrasekhar

Comment: I believe there is a time step parameter that the engine takes when starting, ttrying playing with it.

Comment: @Idog: Could you please provide me any example actually i didn't get you...

Comment: I think Idog is referring to the step() method in your world object. I believe it takes in a time value. Try playing with smaller/different time values, while having the game run at it's own rate.

Comment: @Chandu: Yes, there basically must be a step() function or something analogous to it in the engine since it is a discrete approximation to the continuous case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned already, changing the length of the time step can give a slow motion effect. It also has the side-effect of altering the way gravity affects bodies, and can complicate other things like recording a replay or syncing state across multiplayer games for example.

Another option is to use a fixed time step length for every time step, and keep track of the previous position and angle for all bodies. Then you can interpolate between the last frame and the current frame to draw them at an in-between frames position. This means that you are always drawing things a tiny bit behind their current position in the physics engine, but it should not be noticeable with typical frame-rates of 30-60fps.

Comment: Thanks @ iforce2d it worth for me.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this effect with or without Box2D is to step up a time modifier.

so lets say you move the player in a run function like so:

```
player.x += vel_x;
player.y += vel_y;
```

you could setup a time modifier variable that is initialized to 1

```
var time_mod:Number = 1;
```

then update all your movements as followed

```
player.x += vel_x * time_mod;
player.y += vel_y * time_mod;
```

then when you want "the slow motion effect" change your time_mod variable.  For half of real time change your time_mod to 0.5.  If you want to super speed change it to 2 or 3, super slow? change to 0.3

you get the idea?